# Unable to resolve service "memcache" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

Tags: php, memcached, php-8.1, laminas

I am working on upgrading PHP 7.4 to 8.1 on my Laminas project.

In config/autoload/global.php I have-

'caches' => require **DIR** . '/caches.php',

This is caches.php-

```
    'caches' => array(
        'memcached' => array(
            'adapter' => 'memcache',
            'options' => array(
                'namespace' => 'IDSSO',
                'ttl' => 900, //900 seconds = 15 minutes
            ),
            'plugins' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'exception_handler',
                    'options' => array(
                        'throw_exceptions' => false,
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

I go to my portal and I'm seeing this error-

File:

```
/project/vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:620
```

Message:

```
Unable to resolve service "memcache" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?
```

In my composer.json I added

```
"laminas/laminas-cache-storage-deprecated-factory" : "^1.0.1",
"laminas/laminas-cache" : "3.4.0"
```

and module.config.php I added

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Laminas\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Laminas\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memcache'
        ),
```

I wasn't able to resolve this with these changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this myself.

**1.** I added these packages on `composer.json`-

"laminas/laminas-cache-storage-deprecated-factory" : "^1.0.1",

"laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-memcached" : "^2.1.0"

and then did `composer update`

Alternatively, you can also run-

`composer require laminas/laminas-cache-storage-deprecated-factory` and

`composer require laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-memcached` instead.

**2.** Follow the steps from this url- https://github.com/lifenglsf/php_memcached_dll

```
- copy libmemcached.dll to c:\Windows

- copy php-memcached.dll to you PHP/ext directory
```

**3.** On php.ini add this line-

```
extension=memcached
```

**4.** In caches.php file-

Change 'adapter' => 'memcache', to `'adapter' => 'memcached',`

Once this is done, do a `composer install`, `composer update` and restart your local XAMPP.